# xslt not able read xml tag in xsl:template

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

facing issue while fetching below in my xsl file

```
<MainTag>
    <rootTag SEGMENT="1">
        <Tag1A>sample text1</Tag1A>
        <Tag1B>sample text2</Tag1B>
        <Tag1C>sample text3</Tag1C>
        <Tag1D>sample text4</Tag1D>
     </rootTag>
</MainTag>
```

xsl transformation which i am using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:variable name="attrMapping">
        <Mapping>
            <attr id="Tag1A">sample_map1</attr>
            <attr id="Tag1B">sample_map2</attr>
            <attr id="Tag1C">sample_map3</attr>
            <attr id="Tag1D">sample_map3</attr>
        </Mapping>
    </xsl:variable>
    
    
    <xsl:template match="MainTag">
        <xsl:for-each select="rootTag">
            <xsl:for-each select="$attrMapping/Mapping/*[@id]">              
                <xsl:element name="Value">
                    <xsl:attribute name="AttributeID"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:variable name="val">
                        <xsl:call-template name="valueFinder">
                            <xsl:with-param name="AttrID" select="."></xsl:with-param>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$val"></xsl:value-of>                  
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name = "valueFinder">
        <xsl:param name="AttrID"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="/MainTag/rootTag/$AttrID"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but in the result i am not getting value from xml file (e.g. sample text1)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Value AttributeID="sample_map1"/>
<Value AttributeID="sample_map2"/>
<Value AttributeID="sample__map3"/>
<Value AttributeID="sample__map3"/>
```

what can i change in xslt file to be able to read from source file while i am looping inside a xsl variable

Answer (score 0):

You did not post the expected result. I am guessing you want to do:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="elem-by-name" match="rootTag/*" use="name()" />

<xsl:variable name="attrMapping">
    <Mapping>
        <attr id="Tag1A">sample_map1</attr>
        <attr id="Tag1B">sample_map2</attr>
        <attr id="Tag1C">sample_map3</attr>
        <attr id="Tag1D">sample_map3</attr>
    </Mapping>
</xsl:variable>
    
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="xml" select="." />
    <xsl:for-each select="$attrMapping/Mapping/attr">              
        <Value AttributeID="{.}">
            <xsl:value-of select="key('elem-by-name', @id, $xml)"/>               
        </Value>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the 3rd argument of the `key()` function that returns the context to the input XML.

Note also that the result produced here is an XML fragment, not a well-formed XML document which must have a single root element.